# Add space between components

Tags: android

I have two TextViews in TableRow:

```
        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <TextView
                android:text="Temperature"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:text="Humidity"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"></TextView>


        </TableRow>
```

What is the right way of making small space between them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add margins to right of first TextView and left of second TextView.

```
<TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:text="Temperature" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:text="Humidity" />
</TableRow>
```

[image: Sample 1]

Or you can also add an empty space between the two TextView with required width.

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:text="Temperature" />

<Space
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:text="Humidity" />
```

[image: Sample 2]